# THREE.SVGRenderer save text of image

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

Is there a way to obtain the svg text (an image) from `THREE.SVGRenderer`?

Currently using r58.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access the SVG DOM with `renderer.domElement`

To convert that to XML string (if that is what you mean by "svg text"):

```
var XMLS = new XMLSerializer(); 
var svgfile = XMLS.serializeToString(renderer.domElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try printing the page to PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the response, by printing you mean go to `File->Print->Save` As PDF? Or is there a method to save the frame of a renderer to a file?